# Has anyone used Vertx.io with PostgreSQL?

Tags: java, postgresql, asynchronous, vert.x

Has anyone used Vertx.io with PostgreSQL? I've just found out about Vertx.io and on first look it seems really nice. The thing is that i need to use it with a database where I make queries and then return the output to the user in JSON format (basically some kind of a web service).
Due to it's nature (being async) making a query to the DB will block and will greatly affect performance. So my question would be how does one access/get data from DB in a async way so that it will work with vertx.io?

Answer (score 1):

Either use [async driver](https://github.com/mauricio/postgresql-async) or use a pool of threads which interact with DB and transmit results to vert.x activities. The size of the pool can be small, as database cannot execute many simultaneous queries anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Vert.x has worker verticles to perform tasks like this. Basically you can initialize a worker verticle which will perform the blocking task and then return the results to the verticle which needs it. I wont write any code here since im a beginner myself with Vert.X